# Why do I have double request to authentication endpoint when I use Spring Security + WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, spring-webflux

I try to create a simple authentication schema with Reactive approach.
I've created a project from scratch with dependencies to reactive components and security.
Introduced Configuration file where I configure authentication manager and security context repository.
The problem is that I notice, that Mono injected into controller initiates double requests to "login" endpoint.

Why does it happens and how to prevent it?

Here is the code of configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class WebFluxSecurityConfiguration {


    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;


    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(
            ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Here is the authentication manager

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {
    private final WebClient webClient;

    public AuthenticationManager(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/login")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
    }
    @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        return webClient.post()
                .header("Authorization","Bearer bla-bla")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .map(r->new AuthenticatedUser());
    }
}
```

And here is a security context repository

```
@Component
public class SecurityContextRepository implements ServerSecurityContextRepository {

    private static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    List<PathPattern> pathPatternList;

    public SecurityContextRepository(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        PathPattern pathPattern1 = new PathPatternParser().parse("/login");
        pathPatternList = new ArrayList<>();
        pathPatternList.add(pathPattern1);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono load(ServerWebExchange swe) {

        ServerHttpRequest request = swe.getRequest();

        RequestPath path = request.getPath();
        if (pathPatternList.stream().anyMatch(pathPattern -> pathPattern.matches(path.pathWithinApplication()))) {
            System.out.println(path.toString() + " path excluded");
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        System.out.println("executing logic for " + path.toString() + " path");

        String authHeader = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        String authToken = null;
        //test
        authHeader = "Bearer bla-bla";
        //~test
        if (authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            authToken = authHeader.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, "");
        }else {
            System.out.println("couldn't find bearer string, will ignore the header.");
        }
        if (authToken != null) {
            Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authToken, authToken);
            return this.authenticationManager.authenticate(auth).map((authentication) -> new SecurityContextImpl(authentication));
        } else {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> save(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, SecurityContext securityContext) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

[link to repository of full project](https://github.com/RassulYunussov/webfluxsecurity.git)

Comment: Why are you setting the token as both username and password? And why are you not using the built in jwt filter in spring 5?

Comment: This is just a synthetic application, where I check hypothesis. The goal is to implement authorization in reactive app with third party authorization server. The client comes with some token, by using which I can extract user profile from authorization server and then implement filtering of request. The problem of this app is that - when I try to get a Principal in controller - the webclient makes a second request to authorization server. And how to avoid it?

Comment: and i will then ask a again since you didnt answer my question, why dont you use the build in functionality of JWTs in spring 5 it has all the customisability you need?

Comment: I think I need to make an investigation of reactive stack and provided built in functionality more. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution to this particular case is to implement caching of WebClient result. So inside of post method to authorization server for retrieval of user profile I just introduced a method cache().

```
   return webClient.post()
                .header("Authorization","Bearer bla-bla")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .cache()
                .map(r->new AuthenticatedUser());
```

That helped to avoid repeating queries to authorization endpoint during the request.